# .NET Core 3.1 Linq and SQL Server can not translate DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a project that is running on .NET Core 3.1 and has Entity Framework Core included.

My problem is I am trying to filter an object by a `datetime` field. The search term is a string and can be anything. The `DateTime` field is being displayed in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` so I believe that using that format in the `ToString` is appropriate.

Here is the code:

```
entitiesFromRepository = entitiesFromRepository.Where(m => m.DepartureDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").Contains(searchTerm));
```

The `entitiesFromRepository` is an `IQueryable`.

The issue I believe is the `ToString` with a date format, as when I take the date format out it works.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: You'd probably be better off trying to determine if the `searchTerm` holds a date in the format yyyy-MM-ddd, parse that to a `DateTime` and use that to query the database.

Comment: sure but what about allowing for just the year part of the field or the year and month?

Comment: You could represent searching for a year (2022) as `DepartureDate >= 2022/01/01 && DepartureDate < 2023/01/01` and a month as (Match for example) `DepartureDate >= 2022/03/01 && DepartureDate < 2022/04/01`. Obviously you'd need to hold the dates in `DateTime` objects and write the query appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can try TryParse your "search term"

```
    DateTime date;
    DateTime.TryParse("search term", out date);
    entitiesFromRepository = entitiesFromRepository.Where(m => m.DepartureDate.Date == date).ToList();

//this will work perfect if your "search term" comes as "2022-03-31" eg
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to use `.ToString()` on datetime but there is a trick that you can achieve your query like this:

```cs
entitiesFromRepository.Where(x => 
(x.DepartureDate.Year.ToString() 
+ "-" + 
x.DepartureDate.Month.ToString() 
+ "-" + 
x.DepartureDate.Day.ToString())
.Contains(searchTerm));
```

I've tested in .net 6 and works fine but I think it should work on .netcore 3.1 too.